# Summing values of common keys in two dictionaries efficiently

Tags: python, list, performance, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
arr1 = {749: 3}
arr2 = {652: -1, 790: -1, 749: 5}
```

I want to get arr3 such that values of common keys from arr1 and arr2 are summed.

`arr3 = {652: -1, 790: -1, 749: 8}`. It doesn't need to be sorted.

Time performance is very important. Code I'm using so far:

```
summated = {k : sum(i for i in (arr1.get(k), arr2.get(k)) if i is not None) for k in arr1.keys() | arr2}
```

To remove keys that have value=0:

```
{k:v for k,v in summated.items() if v}
```

Comment: What does the "To remove keys that have value=0" code have to do with your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Counter class from collections:

```
from collections import Counter

arr1 = {749: 3}
arr2 = {652: -1, 790: -1, 749: 5}

summated = Counter(arr1)
summated.update(arr2)

print(summated)
Counter({749: 8, 652: -1, 790: -1})
```

If you don't want to use a library, you should use a low level copy (instead of a loop or comprehension) for the larger dictionary, and then update the copy with keys from the other dictionary:

```
small,large = sorted((arr1,arr2),key=len)
summated = large.copy()
summated.update((k,summated.get(k,0)+v) for k,v in small.items())

print(summated)
{652: -1, 790: -1, 749: 8}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply loop once over each dictionary and each key/value:

```
arr1 = {749: 3}
arr2 = {652: -1, 790: -1, 749: 5}

arr3 = {}
for d in [arr1, arr2]:
    for k,v in d.items():
        arr3[k] = arr3.get(k, 0)+v
```

Output: `{749: 8, 652: -1, 790: -1}`

**If you only had positive values**, you could use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

arr3 = Counter(arr1)+Counter(arr2)
```

And if you want to delete keys with 0 as value, you can also do it on the fly:

```
arr1 = {749: 3, 790: 1}
arr2 = {652: -1, 790: -1, 749: 5}

arr3 = {}
for d in [arr1, arr2]:
    for k,v in d.items():
        arr3[k] = arr3.get(k, 0)+v
        if not arr3[k]:
            del arr3[k]
```

Output: `{749: 8, 652: -1}`

Comment: @Pranav they want the common keys to be added, but the unique ones to retain their value, else the output wouldn't be `arr3 = {652: -1, 790: -1, 749: 8}` but `arr3 = {749: 8}`